# How do I make my PhoneGap Android APP fit all devices?

Tags: java, android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I built my APP as was instructed using Cordova, and I can't get the HTML pages I make to fit the scree, they're always larger.

This is the generated Android App Code, and there was no .xml file generated for layout

```
public class APP extends CordovaActivity 
{
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();
    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
    //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

And I put this in the Meta tag, of the HTML file.

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0" >
```

Running this App gives me an app that is much bigger than the size of the screen, also I use JQuery Mobile to structure the HTML, any solutions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not much can be suggested to you unless you show us your HTML and CSS code, this is a common problem when creating apps using web technologies for devices with vastly different screen resolutions.

One work around would be to define the dimensions of UI elements in `em` units instead of `px`. Then you could set appropriate base `font-size` for different screen resolutions using CSS media queries or JavaScript

Comment: This is what is annoying me, I'm not using an PX, I did the entire UI in %, so that it fits the screen in question, I think it is a problem with Cordova/PhoneGap, I'm still not sure.

Answer (score 0):

---

Usually I want pages not to have a page width of 800 to 900 pixels, as the Android and iPhone browsers set it to by default. To have the page width the same as the device width, I set the following meta tags:

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no" />
```

Also refer https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html

Comment: This did not work, I think the problem is that the android device picks it up as a CordovaActivity, or an App with a webView or something as such, that I don't have much control over. i.e, It would have worked if I was trying to open an HTML page using an Android Browser, this is an app using HTML.

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
```

100% works. you can view my app here.

http://www.revivalx.com/my/#home